# Cannot convert string variable to raw

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have seen few examples on how to convert string variable to raw one using interpolation, but it doesn't work for me:

```
import json


j = '{"value": "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"}'

print(j)
print(fr"{j}")
print(r'{"value": "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"}') # Works
print(json.loads(r'{"value": "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"}'))
try:
    print(json.loads(fr"{j}"))  # Doesn't work
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `j` does not represent valid JSON. The backslashes in the string literal -- assigned to `j` -- serve no purpose.

Comment: @h0r53, that is not true.

Comment: @trincot this is valid JSON

Comment: no, `j` does not have valid JSON. Just look at what the first `print` outputs.

Comment: check it with https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @trincot the error is for the last line

Comment: Please re-read the comments. You're _not starting with valid JSON_ so it's pointless to discuss what drops out at the end

Comment: @roganjosh this is VALID JSON.

Comment: `print(j)` -> `{"value": "{"foo": "bar"}"}` which is NOT valid JSON

Comment: THERE IS NO SUCH THING AS A RAW STRING!  There are only raw string *literals*, which affect how backslashes are interpreted when written directly in the source code - the resulting string object is completely indistinguishable from any other string containing the same characters.  The concept of "raw" simply does not apply to anything you do with strings at runtime.

Comment: raw is a special mode how string literals are interpreted and converted to strings. This happens during bytecode generation. String interpolation happens mainly at runtime and inserts strings (not string literals) into other strings (there is more but not relevant here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
j = '{"value": "{\\"foo\\": \\"bar\\"}"}'

print(json.loads(j))
```

In order for it to be valid JSON, the `\` has to present to escape the quotes. So, you'd need to escape the backslashes in the original string.

Answer (score 0):

For the string to be valid JSON, you'll want it to have the literal backslashes in it. But what your script assigns to `j` is a string *without* literal backslashes. The ones that appear in your code are escapes for the character that follows.

The first `print` statement proves this point, since it outputs this:

```
{"value": "{"foo": "bar"}"}
```

And this is not valid JSON.

The quick fix is to use an `r` string in the first statement:

```
j = r'{"value": "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"}'
```

Now it will work.

Comment: This is escaped JSON in JSON and it is VALID

Comment: I need to make it raw from a variable, not a string declaration

Comment: @Roman, no, it is not valid. The escape is applied to the **string literal** (when not using `r`), so it is consumed, and does not find its way to the string that is assigned to `j`. Like I wrote in my answer, just check what it prints, ... that is **NOT** valid JSON. Even the syntax highlighting provided by SO shows that it is wrong.

Comment: `r` and `f` work on literals. If you start with wrong JSON, you're lost. You need to start with valid JSON.

Comment: The answer to your question "What am I doing wrong?" is just that: you start with non-JSON.

Answer (score 0):

import json

j = '{"value": "{"foo": "bar"}"}'

## Use double curly braces to escape the backslashes within the f-string

formatted_string = fr"{{'value': {j}}}"

print(json.loads(formatted_string))